# EasyAutocomplete - ajax update options object on every keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I have an input box, where people are supposed to be typing in a city name, and it should get autocompleted dynamically, by sending to the API what they typed in, matching it on the backend to the current available jobs, and sending back via ajax an array of results, which then is supposed to dynamically update the options data array, in the EasyAutocomplete plugin.

Here is the code:

```
$(function () {
    var minlength = 3;
    $(document).on('keyup','#mainSearch2',function( ) {
        var that = this,
        inputVal2 = $("#mainSearch2").val();

        if (inputVal2.length >= minlength ) {
            if (searchRequest != null) 
                searchRequest.abort();
            searchRequest = 
            $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: 'myurltotheapi',
                  data: {
                    apiKey: "myapikey", // required
                    city: inputVal2,
                    page: 0, // optional, which page of the results, starts at "0", defaults to "0"
                    perPage: 20 // optional, results per page, defaults to "20"
                  },
                  success: function (apiResponse2){
                      if (inputVal2==$(that).val()) {
                    //Receiving the result of search here
                        options = {data: []};
                        options.data = apiResponse2.locations.map(function (el) {
                          return el.city+", "+el.state;
                        });
                        $("#mainSearch2").easyAutocomplete(options);
                     }
                    }
        });
        }
    });
});
```

So what currently happens, is that on every key stroke after the 3rd character, the autocomplete list under the input refreshes itself to the correct values, but that entire windows then dissapears altogether a split second after showing the results. The input box also loses the focus, so you have to manually click back in, to type more (but you can't select any easyautocomplete results, since they dissappear so fast, and appear only on next key stroke for a split second)  In chrome dev tools, the ".easy-autocomplete" div class looks like gets deleted and added again.

I'm wondering whether there is a better way to do this, without all these keyups, whether EasyAutocomplete maybe supports some way to dynamically send the value on every keystroke and pull the content from the API results to the options.data array & apply it without losing focus on the input box and the dissapearing easyautocomplete results window.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer:

```
$(function() {
    $('#mainSearch2').easyAutocomplete({
    url: 'myurl',
    ajaxSettings: {
      dataType: "json",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        apiKey: "myapikey"
      }
    },
    listLocation: "suggestions",
    preparePostData: function(data) {
        data.query = $('#mainSearch2').val();
      return data;
    },
    requestDelay: 400
  });
});
```